# java.util.date object to javascript date string

Tags: javascript, java, datetime

I'm getting java date json object from API. I need to convert it to javascript date format.

here's the java.util.date object:

`{ month: 11, _classname: "java.util.Date", class: "java.util.Date", _type: "JavaClass", timezoneOffset: -360, day: 5, time: 1071165600000, year: 103, date: 12, seconds: 0, minutes: 0, hours: 0 }`

I want to show this object as readable date string in HTML element.

ex. 16 December 2019

Comment: Well, you have `day`, `month`, `year`, `hours`, `minutes` and `seconds` fields to start with. There is also `time`. What's the exact problem with using those?

Comment: In otherside I have entered 11/Dec/2003. but, How do I convert these values to js string?

Comment: I have solved my problem. Code attached. Thanks!

Comment: The data do carry all the marks of the very poor design of the `java.util.Date` class, though. month 11 is not November, but December since months are numbered from 0. The time zone offset has non-standard sign, so -360 means +06:00. `day` means day of week and is numbered from Sunday (0) against the ISO 8601 standard. Year 103 means 2003 (believe it or not). (So no, the date in the example does not represent 16 December 2019.)

Comment: @OleV.V. Thank you very much for the info. But, the result API couldn't be changed, and the best part is I got this solved by converting **time** attribute value using GB timezone. The result I got is 100% correct since I have given the same in to the system. so the attributes in the object are garbage data apart from **time** attribute value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by adding below function:

```
var accOpenedDate = [];
 const monthsList = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
 var yearOnly;
 var dateObj;

 for (var jdateCount = 0; jdateCount < resArray.DMS_MultipleDates.length; jdateCount++){
  dateObj = resArray.DMS_MultipleDates[jdateCount];
  FromattedDateTime = new Date(dateObj["time"]).toLocaleDateString("en-GB", { day: 'numeric', month: 'long', year: 'numeric' });
}

//FormattedDateTime = 16 Dec 2019
```